# Let $S=\{a,b,c\}$. Define a function $f\;:\;P(S) \rightarrow \{0,1,2,3\}$ where $f(A)=|A|$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am stuck on defining the function. What is $A$, is it a set? How am I meant to find $f$ when I input $A$ which might be a SET and not an element into it? Is the $|A|$ referring to cardinality or absolute value? I don't understand how am I even meant to begin, and I don't fully understand the question either.

Comment: $A$ is a set whatever; in your case, an element of $\mathcal P(S)$ i.e. a *subset* of $S$.

Comment: Your are not asked to do anyting! You are just given the definition of  a function $f$ and no task to do.

Comment: I believe $P(S)$ denotes the power set of $S,$ so the set of all subsets of $S.$ So yes, if $A$ is a member of $P(S)$ the it is a subset of $S$ and $|A|$ denotes the cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a bit confusing at first to have a function defined on a collection of subsets of a set. Nevertheless, working through it:

- $P(S)$ is the collection of all subsets of $S := \{a,b,c\}$. There are eight different subsets of $S$.
- $f$ is the function that takes a subset $A$ of $\{a,b,c\}$ and outputs a number $f(A)$ between $0$ and $3$. The number $f(A)$ it outputs is the size $|A|$ of the set.

e.g. If $A = \{a,c\}$, then $f(A) = 2$, since $\{a,c\}$ contains two elements.
Another example is to take $A$ equal to the empty set $\varnothing$ (which is indeed a subset of $\{a,b,c\}$). In this case $f(\varnothing) = 0$.

Comment: How can $A=\{1,3\}$ when $A$ is a subset of $S$ which is $\{a,b,c\}$?

Comment: Oh! That's a typo on my part. I meant $A = \{a,c\}$. Sorry and thanks - it's fixed now.